# Who are the nine Pirate Lords?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

*Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End* mentions the Pirate Lords. It states that there are nine Pirate Lords. Hector Barbossa tells a story about Calypso and how the Bretheran court acts on binding her in human form.

Obviously Jack Sparrow and Hector Barbossa are among them. Who are the other Lords?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From Pirates [Wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Lord),

> The nine Pirate Lords as of the meeting of the Fourth Brethren Court.
>
> - Ammand - Pirate Lord of the Black Sea
> - Hector Barbossa - Pirate Lord of the Caspian Sea
> - Chevalle - Pirate Lord of the Mediterranean Sea
> - Mistress Ching - Pirate Lord of the Pacific Ocean
> - Jocard - Pirate Lord of the Atlantic Ocean
> - Jack Sparrow - Pirate Lord of the Caribbean Sea
> - Sumbhajee Angria - Pirate Lord of the Indian Ocean
> - Elizabeth Swann - Pirate Lord of the South China Sea (later voted as Pirate King)
> - Eduardo Villanueva - Pirate Lord of the Adriatic Sea

**Note:** *Originally There was no Elizabeth Swann, She only made Lord after Sao Feng's death. You can replace Swann with Feng if you're looking for more authenticity.*

The first bretheran court is responsible on binding Calypso in human bonds. from [wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Brethren_Court), They wanted to have rule of the sea belong to men.

> The first Brethren Court made the alliance with Captain Jones, and
>   that right has been passed down through the ages, to the assembled
>   Pirate Lords. ―Mistress Ching

They were aided by then Calypso's lover Davy Jones. Wikia page further explains about first bretheran court,

> Contrary to the belief that the First Meeting of the Brethren Court
>   convened in the days before the great Hellenic society of Greece was
>   founded ([Reference](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pirates%27_Guidelines)), the First Court actually met at a later
>   date, possibly during the 17th century before the Golden Age of Piracy
>   began. The First Court consisted of the Nine Pirate Lords who bound
>   the sea goddess Calypso in her human form, on the instruction of Davy
>   Jones, who revealed them secrets from the Journal of the Ancient Seas.
>   They sealed Calypso's fate with Nine Pieces of Eight, so that the rule
>   of the seas would belong to men. The Brethren would convene a further
>   three times before Calypso's eventual release.

Comment: Hmm, Barbossa was kind of far from his "home" when he mutinied against Sparrow.

Comment: There is also The Legends of the Brethren Court series that takes place right after the young Jack Sparrow series if you would like more information, as thr Pirate Lords were dealing with The Shadow Lord: http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_Legends_of_the_Brethren_Court

Answer (score 13):

[Wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Lord) listed them pretty well:

> The nine Pirate Lords as of the meeting of the Fourth Brethren Court.
>
> > [Ammand](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Ammand) - Pirate Lord of the Black Sea
> >
> > [Hector Barbossa](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Hector_Barbossa) - Pirate Lord of the Caspian Sea
> >
> > [Chevalle](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Chevalle) - Pirate Lord of the Mediterranean Sea
> >
> > [Ching](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Ching) - Pirate Lord of the Pacific Ocean
> >
> > [Jocard](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jocard) - Pirate Lord of the Atlantic Ocean
> >
> > [Jack Sparrow](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Sparrow) - Pirate Lord of the Caribbean Sea
> >
> > [Sumbhajee Angria](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Sumbhajee_Angria) - Pirate Lord of the Indian Ocean
> >
> > [Elizabeth Swann](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Elizabeth_Swann) - Pirate Lord of the South China Sea (later voted as Pirate King)
> >
> > [Eduardo Villanueva](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Eduardo_Villanueva) - Pirate Lord of the Adriatic Sea

Due to questionability of the source, here is the scene itself:

And from the [script](http://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/Pirates_Of_The_Caribbean_At_Worlds_End.pdf):

> JACK: I call for a vote!
>
> Barbossa is dismayed. AMMAND: (raises hand) I vote for Ammand the Corsair.
>
> CHEVALLE: Capitaine Chevalle, the penniless Frenchman
>
> PUSAN: Sri Sumbhajee declares for Sri Sumbhajee.
>
> MISTRESS CHING: Mistress Ching.
>
> JOCARD: Gentleman Jocard.
>
> ELIZABETH: Elizabeth Swann.
>
> BARBOSSA: Barbossa.
>
> VALLENUEVA: Vallenueva.
>
> JACK: Elizabeth Swann.